# Probably a bug in GeoShape filter (NEST)

Tags: c#, json, elasticsearch, nest

Not sure where the bug lies but here's what i came into.
The following code (a GeoShape filtered query) :

```
List<List<double>> gs_polygone_quiberon = new List<List<double>>() { 
            new List<double>() {-3.183515, 47.542491} 
            , new List<double>(){-3.095624, 47.537624} 
            , new List<double>(){-3.026788, 47.478487}
            , new List<double>() {-3.190896, 47.452956}
            , new List<double>() {-3.183515, 47.542491} 
        };

var results = client.Search<Elastic_Oi>(s => s
    .AllIndices()
    .From(0)
    .AllTypes()
    .Size(10)
    .Query(q => q.Filtered(
                f => f.Filter(x =>
                    x.GeoShape("GeoShapeLocation", d => d.Type("polygon").Coordinates(gs_polygone_quiberon))
                    )
                )
    )
);
```

generates the following JSon :

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "geo_shape": {
          "GeoShapeLocation": {
            "shape": {
              "type": "polygon",
              "coordinates": [
                [
                  -3.183515,
                  47.542491
                ],
                [
                  -3.095624,
                  47.537624
                ],
                [
                  -3.026788,
                  47.478487
                ],
                [
                  -3.190896,
                  47.452956
                ],
                [
                  -3.183515,
                  47.542491
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and an 400 error in NEST.

Executing the Json directly in ES generates a null pointer exception. To be able to execute the query i have to add an indentation level in the "coordinates" field like in the following Json (i wrapped all the "coordinates" field value in []

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "geo_shape": {
          "GeoShapeLocation": {
            "shape": {
              "type": "polygon",
              "coordinates": [[
                [
                  -3.183515,
                  47.542491
                ],
                [
                  -3.095624,
                  47.537624
                ],
                [
                  -3.026788,
                  47.478487
                ],
                [
                  -3.190896,
                  47.452956
                ],
                [
                  -3.183515,
                  47.542491
                ]
              ]]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query works like a charm, but is impossible to reproduce using Nest, the `Coordinates` method of the GeoShape filter takes a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>>` parameter, not a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>>>` parameter.

Is the bug in Nest ? My code ? ES ?

Thanks in advance !

Mike

Comment: deleted comment. Used the "Answer your own question" functionnality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Answering" my own question. This was in deed a bug in NEST, as we can see in the NEST author comment https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues/776